# Envers Audit table does not copy created_at, modified_at data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I use Spring Boot, JPA and Hibernate/Envers to get some audit logging going. Tables are setup and Envers is working - but not for all fields.

In every `_aud` table the auto-generated fields `created_at` or `modified_at` are empty. In the original table, the dates are set as expect - but then don't get copied to the audit table.

How can I get Envers (or Hibernate) to copy the full row, including all data (programmatically set or not).

I based my setup on [this tutorial](https://sunitc.dev/2020/01/21/spring-boot-how-to-add-jpa-hibernate-envers-auditing/#3.0)

Comment: Could you share the entity model that you are using?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue